# Django - CreateView specifying a form to use from forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to use a form I have defined in forms.py within my CreateView, as I have css classes and field labels I want to apply.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms) states declaring a form_class field within your CreateView, but trying to set it as my ModelForm gives me the error **TypeError 'AssessmentForm' object is not callable**

```py
class AssessmentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Assessment
    form_class = AssessmentForm()
...
```

What is the proper implementation of setting a ClassBasedView to use a ModelForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that you are calling this `AssessmentForm()`. So instead of using this

```py
form_class = AssessmentForm()
```

use this:

```py
form_class = AssessmentForm
```

And if you deep dive into `CreateView` you came to know that this `class` is using `FormMixin` that has a method name `get_form`, with the implementation something like this.

```py
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

and `get_form_class()` simply returns your `self.form_class`, something like this.

```py
def get_form_class(self):
    """Return the form class to use."""
    return self.form_class
```

Comment: Ah of course, thank you!